# How to increase the size of memory used by visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, out-of-memory

I am using Asp.net with C# to re-ranking a collection image based on their content. But, since I run it, I obtained the following error. While my laptop has 4 GB RAM an 320 GB Hard Disk.

`exception of type 'system.outofmemoryexception' was thrown`

How can increase RAM for running my program?

Comment: please share your code, input, expected output to create a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe you should look to optimize your code, try releasing images from memory when not using it, if that is possible.

Comment: If you are using GDI to process the images, be aware that GDI loves to throw `OutOfMemoryException` for a lot of problems that are not related to being out of memory.  Often times it throws this error when the file you are trying to process is not actually an image, or the file is corrupted in some way.

Comment: "How can increase RAM?" buy more RAM?

Answer (score 2):

It is nearly impossible to give you a good answer without seeing some code, but odds are that you are not actually running out of memory.

GDI will throw an `OutOfMemoryException` for many problems that are not related to memory at all.  It can happen when you try to process a file that isn't actually an image, when the file is corrupt, or when it is an image format that GDI doesn't support.

First, check to make sure that every file or data stream you are processing is actually a real image file.  If you are absolutely sure that the files are valid, and the format is supported by GDI, only then would I start looking at actual memory problems.

Answer (score -1):

Two options - 
  1) there's a bug in your code and it isn't freeing things up.
  2) 4GB of RAM isn't a lot.

Visual Studio will use as much memory as the laptop has.  But you can "extend" it by enabling Virtual Memory - which I suspect is disabled on your computer.  Virtual Memory (aka paging file) allows the Operating System to use diskspace.

However, it will be slow because RAM is written/read to disk as needed.  You laptop is probably already slow enough.

Your best bet is to **buy** more RAM for your laptop.  8GB would be good enough (it is what I have on my "play around" laptop) --- 16GB is even better!

To enable virtual memory on Windows 7 - Open the System Properties (search for it or press the  and Pause button).  Select tab "Advanced" and open Performance Settings.  Next select "Advanced" tab and press "Change..."    Automatically Manage Paging and/or "System managed size"  ("No paging file" disables Virtual Memory).

It is disabled by default because of the performance impact.  Your PC will be slower because it reads/writes to disk...which is many times slower than Memory (RAM).  But it works.

If you can - Buy more memory.  You'll be happier.

Comment: Ummm, it is never disabled by default. Windows relies on the pagefile to function, the Advice to turn off your page file is from the windows XP days. Things have changed a lot sence then.

Comment: Not true.  Some PCs still are sent with pagefile disabled.  I don't know who makes the choice - but I still find Windows 7 machines in the "off" position.   Haven't seen enough Win10 yet to know what the "typical" defaults are.

Comment: While I don't have lots of data or "proof" - seems that it is typically disabled on laptops and enabled on desktops.  I suspect to reduce disk access and save battery life.  But I only have anecdotal evidence.

Comment: Not a single major manufacture does this. Either the user is switching it off and saying they found it that way or you are using a manufacturer who does not understand how modern windows works. Modern applications are written and complied with the assumption that there will be a virtual store for allocated but untouched memory. Have a read [through this SU answer](http://superuser.com/questions/943175/windows-says-ram-ran-out-while-there-is-still-4-gb-of-physical-memory-available/943185#943185)

Comment: Thanks.   Which brings up another idea - maybe his disk is full and the pagefile cannot grow anymore.   But again - 4GB and Visual Studio is a very low amount and will cause plenty of swapping - 8GB would make life better.  Figuring out why his program is giving him out of memory - first it is a good idea to figure out the commit limit on the device.  So is a possible "second answer" to his question -- Empty the Trash?

Comment: No, i think Bradly's answer is the correct one. If you don't call Dispose on GDI objects it frequently will cause you to get Out of Memory exceptions. Also GDI is known for throwing OOM when you give it a malformed image.